# Binary search condition

Tags: java, c++, binary-search

I'm always confused about the condition of the binary search algorithm and it costs me a lot of time in programming contests. My question is when to use each of these conditions?
1. `while (low < high)`
2. `while (high - low > 1)`
3. `while (low <= high)`
`low` = the lowest value in the set of solutions.
`high` = the largest value in the set of solutions.

Comment: Can you tell us your definition of `low` and `high`?

Comment: Without more code / information, this can´t be answered.

Comment: Like any recursive process, you need to think through your base case. That must be a case that will always be reached and that you are prepared to handle without further recursion.

Comment: @deviantfan that's exactly why I asked the question, because I don't know when to use each one of them in any kind of binary search problem, I just try each one of them until one of them works, no logical reason, just intuition.

Comment: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/BinarySearch.java.html might give you some ideas

Comment: I believe this question is very clearly asked (atleast after edits). Why it's still closed?

Answer (score 12):

1. `while (low < high)` is used when you're searching the range `[low, high)`. When updating `high`, use `high = mid`. When updating `low`, use `low = mid + 1`.
2. `while (high - low > 1)` is used when you're searching the range `(low, high)`. When updating `high`, use `high = mid`. When updating `low`, use `low = mid`.
3. `while (low <= high)` is used when you're searching the range `[low, high]`. When updating `high`, use `high = mid - 1`. When updating `low`, use `low = mid + 1`.

Code below:

```
public class BinarySearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] nums = { 4, 9, 12, 18, 20, 26, 28, 29, 55 };

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(binarySearch1(nums, nums[i]));
            System.out.println(binarySearch2(nums, nums[i]));
            System.out.println(binarySearch3(nums, nums[i]));
        }
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int binarySearch1(T[] array, T value) {
        final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
        int low = 0;
        int high = array.length;

        while (low < high) {
            int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
            int comparison = array[mid].compareTo(value);

            if (comparison == 0) {
                return mid;
            } else if (comparison > 0) {
                high = mid;
            } else {
                low = mid + 1;
            }
        }

        return NOT_FOUND;
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int binarySearch2(T[] array, T value) {
        final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
        int low = -1;
        int high = array.length;

        while (high - low > 1) {
            int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
            int comparison = array[mid].compareTo(value);

            if (comparison == 0) {
                return mid;
            } else if (comparison > 0) {
                high = mid;
            } else {
                low = mid;
            }
        }

        return NOT_FOUND;
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int binarySearch3(T[] array, T value) {
        final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
        int low = 0;
        int high = array.length - 1;

        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
            int comparison = array[mid].compareTo(value);

            if (comparison == 0) {
                return mid;
            } else if (comparison > 0) {
                high = mid - 1;
            } else {
                low = mid + 1;
            }
        }

        return NOT_FOUND;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this depend on setting `low = middle` or `low = middle + 1`, and setting `high = middle` or `high = middle - 1`?

Comment: 2) and 3) are not equivalant  when low = 0 and high = 1.

Comment: @Omar Yes.  Here's why: with 1), `low` and `high` have two different meanings.  `low` is an index and `high` is an index plus a count.  When we add `mid` to the mix, it can't semantically be both an index and an index plus a count. Thus, we have to differentiate.  If we update `high`, which is an index plus a count, then we must treat `mid` as an index plus a count and set `high = mid`.  If we update `low`, which is an index, then we must treat `mid` as an index and set `low = mid + 1`.

Comment: @Omar   On the other hand, for 2) and 3), both `low` and `high` are indices. Therefore, when we update `high`, we set `high = mid - 1`, and when we update `low`, we set `low = mid - 1`.

Comment: @JohnKurlak in the latest reply you mean `low = mid + 1`?

Comment: @JohnKurlak btw, I've just used case 2) in this problem [link](http://codeforces.com/contest/192/problem/B)

Comment: @OmarSebres Yes, sorry.  Can't edit comment now.

Comment: @OmarSebres I would have to see your code.

Comment: @JohnKurlak you can find the code [here](https://github.com/OmarSebres/solved-problems/blob/master/CodeForces/Ladders/Div2%20B/B.%20Walking%20in%20the%20Rain.cpp)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80953/discussion-between-omar-sebres-and-john-kurlak).

Comment: I've completely rewritten my answer.  Thanks!